# Magento 2 how override the module template?

Tags: themes, magento2

I added module: `Magefan Blog`

Dir: `app/code/Magefan/Blog/`

My theme:

```
app/design/frontend/Abc/themedir/
```

I use: **magento 2**.

**How override the module template?**

- app/code/Magefan/Blog/view/frontend/templates/

  **to**
- app/design/frontend/Abc/themedir/

***I tried this:***

`1)` create -> app/design/frontend/Abc/themedir/Magefan_Blog/templates/

*and*

`2)` app/design/frontend/Abc/themedir/Magento_MagefanBlog/templates/

But it's not working. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

for layout:

```
- app/design/frontend/Abc/themedir/Magefan_Blog/layout/override/base
```

for template:

```
- app/design/frontend/Abc/themedir/Magefan_Blog/templates
```

Answer (score 1):

didnt work for me ..

I had to created a own template inheritat from current template created (folder, registration.php, theme.xml) and selected in backend

[Template walkthrough](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html)

here my structure to overwrite the templates/widget/recent.phtml template from magefan blog. Tarnava/default is my template name.

```
tarnava-ro@mail:~/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava$ find /var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/registration.php
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/Magefan_Blog
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/Magefan_Blog/templates
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/Magefan_Blog/templates/widget
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/Magefan_Blog/templates/widget/recent.phtml
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/media
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/media/preview.jpg
/var/www/vhosts/tarnava.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava/default/theme.xml
tarnava-ro@mail:~/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Tarnava$
```